# Gerar lista de combinações possíveis

Tags: javascript, string, combinações

Temos 4 times:

```
Time 1 | Time 2 | Time 3 | Time 4
```

Gostaria de saber como construir automaticamente uma lista das combinações possíveis de jogos entre esses times.

**Exemplo:**

```
Time 1 x Time 2 | Time 1 x Time 3 | Time 1 x Time 4 | ...
```

Estou tendo problemas com a lógica para a aplicação.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Para contar os jogos, você precisa fazer uma combinação simples:

```
function combinacaoSimples(n, p) {
    return (fatorial(n) / (fatorial(p) * fatorial(n-p)));
}

function fatorial(n) {
    if(n === 0 || n === 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    for(var i = n; i > 0; --i) {
        n *= i;
    }
    return n;
}

combinacaoSimples(4, 2);
```

Para obter uma lista de combinações possíveis:

```
var i, j, x = [ "Time 1", "Time 2", "Time 3", "Time 4" ],
    combinations = [];
for(i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
    for(j = i + 1; j < x.length; ++j) {
        combinations.push([ x[i], x[j] ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Esse resultado também consegui da seguinte forma:
`$n = 4;
console.log($n*($n-1)/2);`, o que eu preciso e que seja criada a listagem, como segue:
Time 1 x Time 2
Time 2 x Time 3
Time 1 x Time 3
Time 3 x Time 4
...

Comment: Achei que quisesse a quantidade de combinações possíveis. Editei a resposta com o código para conseguir a lista de combinações.